# I need to redirect users to another page based on a code entered

Tags: php, html

I need to create a form on my site where users enter a code and based on that code they're redirected to another page.  Doing it through a database would be more secure but I wouldn't mind if the logic was handled on the form itself.

So, here's an example of what I mean:

Enter Code:  (Box here)

Form searches through list of potential answers( s5d11, wy4sd, lk123, etc.), if it finds a match it redirects to a specific page for each code, if not it gives an error message that the code entered was wrong.

Comment: Do you want to add your code to the question, too?

Comment: What is your question again? What exactly does not work?

Comment: andrewsi -  What do you mean?  The question would just be, "Please enter your code"  The assumption is that the user already knows his or her code.  Then when they enter it, they're taken to the right page if the code entered is correct, if not then they remain on the present page with a message that says that they didn't enter the right code.

Comment: I was thinking about making it loop through an array then redirect but I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example with two files, one html and one php file. The html-page submits the contents of your input to a php-page, which redirects the browser to an URL based on the input.

HTML, index.html:

```
<form action="redirect.php" method="get">
  <input name="mytext" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP, redirect.php:

```
<?
switch($_GET['mytext'])
{
    case 's5d11':
        header('Location: http://somepage.com/');
        break;
    case 'qy4sd':
        header('Location: http://someotherpage.com/');
        break;
    default:
        print "<p>Wrong code. Try again</p>";
        include('index.html');
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, that is too insecure.  I would need it to give an error message if the proper code is not entered and stay on the current page.

Comment: @TomRodgers Now it is more secure. Now it also has a default case, which shows the input field for try-again...

Comment: I got this error message when I tried to enter the code:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/****/public_html/test/redirect.php on line 5

Comment: @TomRodgers Make sure you use the last version of my answer (see above), as a previous version lacked an ending parenthesis before the semicolon...

Comment: Okay, it was the parenthesis you left out on the header locations.  I got it work now.  Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I just whipped this up. You have a code and a path to redirect to for each code. You'll need to apply your own sanitation of course and any other standards. I put them all uppercase...

```
<?php

$_POST['CODE'] = 'CODE'; // Simulate post data...
$array_of_codes = array('CODE' => 'pathtoredirect');
$get_code = addslashes(strtoupper($_POST['CODE']));

if(array_key_exists($get_code, $array_of_codes))
{
    header("Location:".$array_of_codes[$get_code]."");
}else
{
    echo "Error: Code not in array.";
}
?>
```